# Compare different time windows in a plot / lead & lag of moving holidays

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I would like to compare a certain event (e.g. 'Easter') of different years in a plot + include some days before and after the event. So far i am only able to compare the event itself:

```
require('data.table')
require('ggplot2')
require('timeDate')

#create some sample data
a <- data.table(Date = seq(as.Date('2010-01-01'),as.Date('2012-12-31'), 'days'),
            Value = rnorm(1096))
a[as.Date(Easter(year(Date))) == Date,Easter := '1']

#create the plot
ggplot(a[!is.na(Easter),], aes(x=Easter, y=Value, group=as.factor(year(Date)), 
                              colour=as.factor(year(Date)))) + geom_point(size=5)
```

[image]

So what i am doing so far is marking the Easter event in the data.table and using that mark in ggplot. I thought about marking the days before and after as well?

Is there a simpler more elegant way to achieve my goal?

**Update:** I found a way how i can create the graph for Easter (only!)

```
a <- data.table(Date = seq(as.Date('2010-01-01'),as.Date('2012-12-31'), 'days'),
            Value = rnorm(1096))

a[as.Date(Easter(year(Date))) - 15 < Date & as.Date(Easter(year(Date))) + 15 > Date,
  Easter := as.integer(Date - as.Date(Easter(year(Date))))]

ggplot(a[!is.na(Easter),], aes(x=Easter, y=Value, group=as.factor(year(Date)), 
                              colour=as.factor(year(Date)))) +      
       geom_point(size=5) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Any idea how i can achieve the same result based on a column where only the moving holiday is marked (as in the first example above) ?

Comment: Well, you put `aes(x = Easter)` so you got the "Easter" column on the x-axis. I can't reproduce because I don't have an `Easter` function. I tried `forecast::easter()` but that didn't work on your data type.

Comment: Hi Gregor, the Easter function is in the timeDate package, sry i forgot about that one. It is not really important to use Easter, it is just about a random event that comes up once a year and is not at a fixed date.

Comment: what do you try to achieve? plotting the values per year? or plotting the values falling between consecutive easter date??

Comment: I want to compare the values around easter for different years. *Easter just as an example for a moving holiday

Comment: Find the weeks around Easter like this: `timeSequence(Easter(2008, -14), Easter(2008, +14))`.

Comment: The issue is that i have many moving holidays where i don't have that kind of "Easter" function for. That's why i created a column for the Easter event since i have to do it that way with other moving holidays as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#create some sample data
a <- data.table(Date = seq(as.Date('2010-01-01'),as.Date('2012-12-31'), 'days'),
            Value = rnorm(1096))

#mark the event itself
a[as.Date(Easter(year(Date))) == Date,Easter_event := 1]

#extract the indices of the event
event_list <- a[,.I[Easter_event==1]][!is.na(a[,.I[Easter_event==1]])]

#mark +-14 days around the event
for(ind in event_list){
   a[(ind - 14):(ind + 14), Easter := seq(-14,14)]
}
```

That way it works without the "Easter" function and it is possible to use moving holidays like Chinese New Year that are not included in the timeDate package.

Is it possible to do the whole thing without the for-loop?

- Obviously you need to get the dates of the moving holiday (e.g. Chinese New Year) first from google or wherever and put it in the data.table